# What are the website simulators used in adverts called?

Tags: editing, software-recommendation, digitisation

I am working on a Kickstarter project video, and I would like to use footage from the website the project is raising funds for. I know I could use screen recorders, but if I am for example scrolling down the page or moving the mouse it would look uneven as it would have to be done manually. I saw some adverts for Wix, for example [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irYluSTChIY), which use some sort of digitalised version of the website for the shots where the screen is visible to make everything smooth. Are there any tools to do this? If so, what are they called and are there any free/open source examples?

If not, what would be easier: to write an AutoHotKey or similar script to make the mouse movement, or to use Premiere to animate a fake mouse onto it and to move a zoomed-out video recording with keyframes to simulate scrolling? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Make a still image of the website, get another still image of the cursor. In Premiere move the website image to make it look like it's scrolling, and move the mouse layer to look like it's mousing.

Comment: I thought of that, but I still want to know what they are called since I couldn't search for it.

Comment: I don't think that website simulators are a thing. I'd say most times people use Animation™